# Unable to insert image into database with ajax serialize function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Im currently having a trouble to insert an file input (images) into my database, but it return me empty value when I'm trying to insert it into database, other text input are successfully inserted into the database except the image.

Here is my Ajax code where i use to do the ajax function:

```
$("#testing").confirm({
                     confirm: function (el) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'bannerItem.php',
                            data: el.closest('form').serialize(),
                            type: 'post'

                        }).done(function () {
                            if(!alert('Banner Had Successfully Updated.')){document.getElementById('form').reset();}
                        }).fail(function () {
                            //if the post is failed show an error message if you want
                            alert('Some error occur. Please try again later.');
                        }).always(function () {
                            //this is executed on success and failure
                            $('#myhiddendiv').hide();
                        })
                    }
                });
```

Here is the php code:

```
    <?php
    include 'dbConnection.php';

    global $dbLink;


        $target_file = basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        //Check image file type


            // Make sure the file was sent without errors
            if($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0) {

                //Gather all required data
                $item_id = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_POST['banner_id']);
                $name = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_POST['bannerName']);
                $data = $dbLink->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']));



                //Create the SQL query
                $query = "INSERT INTO banner_item (banner_item_id, banner_name,banner_data,banner_created) VALUES ('{$item_id}','{$name}','{$data}', NOW()
                    )";

                //Execute the query
                $result = $dbLink->query($query);

                //Check if it was successfull
                if($result) {

                    echo 'Name : '.$name.'</br>';
                    echo 'Result : Success! Your file was successfully added!';
                }
                else{
                    echo 'Result : Error! Failed to insert the file'
                       . "<pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
                }
            }
            else {
                echo'An error accured while thefile was being uploaded. '
                   . 'Error code: '. intval($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error']);
            }


        // Close the mysql connection
        $dbLink->close();


    // Echo a link back to the main page
    echo '<p>Click <a href="index.html">here</a> to go back</p>';
    ?>
```

If i use the php code withouth the ajax function ,everything can be inserted into the database, but when i use the ajax function only the image can't be inserted into the database.

Here is the form that i used to submit the value:

```
<form id="form" action="bannerItem.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    <div class="box-body">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="banner_id" value="1"></input>
                                        <div class="form-group" >
                                            <label for="bannerName">Banner Name 旗帜名称</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bannerName" id="bannerName" placeholder="Please Enter Name" onChange="checkDisabled(testing);">
                                        </div>
                                         <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
                                            <input type="file" id="uploaded_file" name="uploaded_file"  onChange="checkDisabled(testing);"><br>
                                            <p class="help-block">Your picture size not more than 2MB.  (Only JPEG/JPG/PNG is allowed)</p>
                                        </div>  

                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <button id="testing" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Update</button>      
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!-- /.box-body -->


                                </form>                  <!-- D
```

I'm had been searching around for hours how to solve this in stackoverflow and google, most of them using XHR2 or formData but I'm not sure which one to use and how to use it into my code as I'm still a fresh guy to use the AJAX and PHP function. Please guide me along if i mad any mistake on my Ajax code. Thanks and good day ahead :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't upload files through form serialization. If your browser requirements are over IE9 you can use XHR upload or `FileAPI` plugin

Example:

```
function startUpload() {
    var fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");

    if (fileInput.files.length == 0) {
        alert("Please choose a file");
        return;
    }

    var progressBar = document.getElementById("progressBar");
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
        var percentComplete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
        progressBar.value = percentComplete;
    };

    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            alert("Sucess! Upload completed");
        } else {
            alert("Error! Upload failed");
        }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function() {
        alert("Error! Upload failed. Can not connect to server.");
    };

    progressBar.value = 0;
    xhr.open("POST", "ajax-upload", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", fileInput.files[0].type);
    xhr.send(fileInput.files[0]);
}
```

More information [HERE](https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2013/01/02/uploading-file-using-xmlhttprequest-level-2/)

Comment: Hi there, thanks for giving advice to use the XHR2 , but i still have a text file to be insert together with the images, how can i do to achieve that? Thanks

Comment: To be easier just use FileAPI plugin. I think you can specify available extensions for upload. https://github.com/mailru/FileAPI

Btw, if you're using AngularJS I can help you with a directive.

Answer (score 0):

I had solve my problem with form data function. I know that FireAPI and XHR2 can be done, but for more simple understanding for the beginner like me i think this is a solution to solve my problem. Thanks and i hope that i can help the other with my sample code. :)

Here is the code that i used successfully on my ajax: 
//File and text upload with formDATA function

```
            $("form#form").submit(function(){
            var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url:'bannerItem.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    if(!alert('Banner Had Successfully Updated.')){location.reload();}
                },
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            });

            return false;
        });
```